# Center dynamic Angular form

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have created a form with an add and delete button :

```
<p-growl [(value)]="msgs"></p-growl>
    <div class="center" appMcard>
        <form [formGroup]="GroupRMPM_FG">
            <div formArrayName="GroupId_Name"   *ngFor="let control of GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls; let i= index">
             <input  type="text" pInputText [formControl]="control.controls.Group_Id_Name"/>


                <button pButton type="button" class="delete-btn " *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length > 1" (click)="deleteGroup(i)" icon="fa-minus" >

                </button>
                <button *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length == i+1" pButton type="button" (click)="addNewGroup()" icon="fa-plus formcontainer"  class="add-btn formcontainer"></button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center {
    width: 40%;
    height : 100%;
    min-height: 40vh;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    background-color: #F3F3F3;

    padding: 20px;
}
input {
    font-family: 'bnppSans';
}
.delete-btn {
    background-color: #E61D00;
    border-color: #E61D00;
}
.add-btn {

    background-color: #24b3c7;
    border-color: #24b3c7;

}
.delete-btn:hover {
    background-color: #c61a01 !important;
    border-color: #c61a01 !important;
}
```

Actually here's what I get

[image: Form centred without Delete button]

[image: Form not centred]

The problem is when I add new fields to the `text-align: center` in `center` class, it is not working as expected. I would want the input to be centered like the first field and the buttons get shifted to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS work perfect as it has to, you have to add dummy html element like button/div when there is no second button at right side.

```
<form [formGroup]="GroupRMPM_FG">
        <div formArrayName="GroupId_Name"   *ngFor="let control of GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls; let i= index">
         <input  type="text" pInputText [formControl]="control.controls.Group_Id_Name"/>


            <button pButton type="button" class="delete-btn " *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length > 1" (click)="deleteGroup(i)" icon="fa-minus" >

            </button>
            <button *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length == i+1" pButton type="button" (click)="addNewGroup()" icon="fa-plus formcontainer"  class="add-btn formcontainer"></button>


            <----add dummy element here---->
            <button *ngIf="GroupRMPM_FG.controls.GroupId_Name.controls.length != i+1" pButton type="button" class="dummyElement"></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

CSS:

```
.dummyElement,.dummyElement:hover{
 background-color:transparent;
 color:transparent;
 border-color:transparent;  
 pointer-events: none;
}
```

Note: Anyway you have to hide new dummy element and set to default cursor.

Comment: It's not exactly want I want . When I click on the button the layout is changing

Comment: I got a small problem, even with the :hover refix ,  my button are visible when I put mouse over them

Answer (score 1):

Here is working DEMO of my above answer.

```css
.center{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}
.dummyButton{
  background-color:transparent;
  color:transparent;
  border-color:transparent;  
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <div>
    <input type='text'><input type="button" value="click"><input type="button" value="click" class="dummyButton">
    <br>
    <input type='text'><input type="button" value="click"><input type="button" value="click" class="dummyButton">
    <br>
    <input type='text'><input type="button" value="click"><input type="button" value="click">
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```